# Common Features among Multiple RAMDisks Created Using modprobe brd

Tags: centos, block-device, modprobe, ramdisk

I wanted to create a 60GB RAMDisk to check the read and write performance of it. Using the command `modprobe brd rd_size=62914560`, 16x 60GB RAMDisks have been created: /dev/ram0, /dev/ram1, ..., /dev/ram15.

All these RAMDisks have the same size (60GB). Aggregating their size, I get 960GB while my memory size is 128GB. Why 16 RAMDisks are created and what are the common features among them? Do they have the same memory address range?

Answer (score 1):

16 devices are created because that’s the default value of the `rd_nr` module parameter on your system; that’s the parameter which determines the number of devices created (and thus the maximum number of block devices).

Each block device is separate. They only allocate memory as they are used, so it is possible to have total “disk” space larger than memory — you’ll only run into problems if you try to use too much of it.